# Wordpress automatically adds <div> and <p> between widgets areas, how to avoid it?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

So I have had to edit some code of the template I am using because I need two widget areas in the header, I have managed to achieve it, but the problem comes when Wordpress adds `<div>` and `<p>` between them and I do not want that because I need them in the same line, not in two lines.

This is what I have done so far:

Inside the file `functions.php` I have added a new sidebar in the function `envo_ecommerce_widgets_init()` just after the default sidebar for the header:

```
function envo_ecommerce_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Sidebar', 'envo-ecommerce'),
            'id' => 'envo-ecommerce-right-sidebar',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Top Bar Section', 'envo-ecommerce'),
            'id' => 'envo-ecommerce-top-bar-area',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s col-sm-4">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
    register_sidebar( //this is the default sidebar for the header
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Header Section', 'envo-ecommerce'),
            'id' => 'envo-ecommerce-header-area',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
    register_sidebar( //this is the sidebar I have added
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Centro cabecera', 'envo-ecommerce'),
            'id' => 'envo-ecommerce-center-header-area',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => esc_html__('Footer Section', 'envo-ecommerce'),
            'id' => 'envo-ecommerce-footer-area',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s col-md-3">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
}
```

Then I have added that new sidebar in the file `template-part-topnav.php` which contains the whole structure for the header.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-header-area' ) ) { ?>
  <div class="site-heading-sidebar" >
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-center-header-area' ); ?> //this is the new sidebar I have just created
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-header-area' ); ?> //this is the default sidebar
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The new widget area has been created sucessfully:
[image]

But when I add something to both widget areas, this is the result:

[image]

`bbb` is inside the new widget area and `aaa` is inside the default widget area.

If I inspect the website, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, there are `<div>` and `<p>` between both widget areas and that prevents from placing both widget areas in the same line.

Is there a way to avoid this?

[This](https://wordpress.org/themes/envo-ecommerce/) is the template I am using in case you need it.
Thank you in advance!

Note: When I say "default widget area" I mean, it is the widget area that came with the template by default.

Edit: 
The answer of @Manish Negi has fixed the issue but it only works when I add text. However, I want to place a slider and a login form in them and it is adding another space between them again...

I am using two plugins for that, [MetaSlider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/) and [WordPress Login Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-login-form/)

I add the metaslider shortcode in the first widget area:

[image]

I add the WP login form in the second widget area:

[image]

And this is the result:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, it is adding again a space between the slider and the login form and I want them in the same line.

Comment: The text widget automatically converts text into paragraphs. If you don't want that, try using the built-in HTML widget instead.

Comment: @cabrerahector same results: https://imgur.com/a/JfeIUi2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress text widget automatically converts text into paragraphs. Some CSS can help to get your result.

Replace your code into `template-part-topnav.php` file

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-header-area' ) ) { ?>
<div class="site-heading-sidebar">
    <div class="header-widget-1">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-center-header-area' ); ?> //this is the new sidebar I have just created
    </div>
    <div class="header-widget-2">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-ecommerce-header-area' ); ?> //this is the default sidebar
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And add little CSS styling for this section

```
<style>
.header-widget-1, .header-widget-2{float:left;}
.site-heading-sidebar{clear:both;}
</style>
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you :) this has worked but apparenty it does not work for what I want to add... It does prevent from adding a space if I add text in both widget areas but it does not work if I replace them by a slider and a login form. I have added a slider in the first widget area and a login form in the second widget area. I have edited my main post, so you can see what have I done. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry by the way, I have should said from the beginning that I want those objects, not texts. I just thought it would be the same for any object.

Comment: Can you please check the div container size? which have `.site-heading-sidebar` class. Assuming this class has a fixed width.

Comment: I do not see it has a fixed width in its CSS: https://i.imgur.com/BqNx18A.png, but while I move the mouse over the selector, it appears the size (345 x 0): https://i.imgur.com/RjNk9Fy.png

Comment: In case this is not possible to fix, could you please share with me a free template that has a carousel in its header in case you know if there is any? I want to achieve something like this: https://i.imgur.com/9xhUB9l.png (the logo, the slider and the login form on the same line and in the header)

Comment: Sorry for replying three times, but I have just tried to enable again the previous template which I managed to display this result: https://i.imgur.com/L4ojJcP.png and I prefer this template. So, I have tried to move the login form through CSS code and it does work, but on the mobile version it looks weird. Would you know how to fix it? I have added ```margin-top: -350px;``` to the widget area that contains the form

Comment: Fixed, I've finally managed to fix it by adding ```@media screen and (min-width: 420px) {``` in the CSS rule, so now it looks great on the web version and on the phone version. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Glad! you fixed this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_empty_p( $content ) {
    $content = force_balance_tags( $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '~\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)+</p>\s?~', '', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 20, 1);
```

This code might be useful. Write to functions.php.

Comment: Thanks :) this code probably works, but the answer @Manish Negi has already helped me. Now I am having the same issue by replacing the text for two objects (a slider and a login form), it is adding another space again between them. So, I have also tried to add your code in the functions.php file but it did not fix it either. Any idea? I have edited my main post explaining what I have done, check it out.